# how to get object using nodejs from cypher query?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I have following query which is giving me what I want -:

```
'START user=node({userId}), other=node({otherId})',
      'MATCH (user) -[rels?]-> (other)',
      'RETURN rels'
```

but I'm unable to access the object it send.I need following high lightened object which I have no idea to access.

Object is inspected in console below -:

```
[{"rels":{"db":{"url":"http://localhost:7474","_request":{},"_root":..........{},"start":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/222","property":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/245/properties/{key}","self":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/245","properties":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/245/properties","type":"knows","end":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/196","data":{"created_at":1372829579654}},"_start":{"db":{"url":"http://localhost:7474","_request":{},"_root":...
```

Full program:

```
User.checkRelationship = function (user, fid, callback) {

  var uids = [user.uid, fid];
  async.map(uids, User.by_uid, function (err, usernodes) {
    if (!err && usernodes && usernodes.length) {
    User.relsCheck(usernodes, function (err, rels) {
        if (!err && rels) {
          callback(null, rels);  // inpecting rels gave the above object but I want to return rels.type , but is not giving i want
        } else {
          callback(err || new Error('relationships does\'nt exists'));
        }
      });
    } else {
      callback(err || new Error('Unable to fetch user nodes: ' + uids.join(',')));
    }
  });
};


User.relsCheck = function (nodes, callback) {
  if (nodes.length !== 2) {
    return callback(new Error('Invalid/insufficient arguments'));
  }
  var query = [
      'START user=node({userId}), other=node({otherId})',
      'MATCH (user) -[rels?]-> (other)',
      'RETURN rels'
  ].join('\n');

  var params = {
    userId: nodes[0].node().id,
    otherId: nodes[1].node().id,
  };

   db.query(query, params, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the raw result, maybe just to a raw $.post and read the result?